# Can we apply quadratic optimization in complex inner product spaces?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

As I said in my previous question, I am revisiting Peter J Olver's [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/3223_2019-10-28-13-12-55.pdf). I am on chapter 9, "A General Framework for Linear PDEs". The author has been discussing some results about inner product spaces having to do with self-adjoint, positive definite linear operators. He gives the following important result, on page 362 of the linked text:

> Let $S:U\to U$ be a self-adjoint positive definite linear operator on a [**real**] inner product space $U$. Suppose that the linear system $$Su=f$$ admits a (necessarily unique) solution $u_\star$. Then $u_\star$ minimizes the value of the associated quadratic function(al) $$Qu=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su\rangle-\langle f,u\rangle$$ meaning that $Qu_\star < Qu$ for all admissable $u\neq u_\star$ in $U$.

(Firstly, the last line I think makes an overly strong assumption that this minimum is achieved *uniquely* at $u_\star$, which I can't easily find a justification for, but that is not the main point of my question. )

The author's proof is pretty hard to follow, but I managed to find one [here](https://sites.calvin.edu/scofield/courses/m333/F09/calendar/notesOnFEM.pdf) that includes a few more steps. It goes as follows:
\begin{align*}
Qu&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su\rangle-\langle u,f\rangle\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su\rangle-\langle u,Su_\star\rangle\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su_\star\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle u,Su_\star\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,S(u-u_\star)\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle u_\star,Su\rangle \tag{3}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u,S(u-u_\star)\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\left(\langle u_\star,S(u-u_\star)\rangle+\langle u_{\star},S(u_\star-u)\rangle\right)}_{=0}-\frac{1}{2}\langle u_\star, Su\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle u-u_\star,S(u-u_\star)\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle u_\star, Su_\star\rangle
\end{align*}
(1) follows because, since we are in a real inner product space, the inner product is truly symmetric. (2) follows because $f=Su_\star$. (3) follows because of symmetry of the inner product, and the fact that $S$ is both self-adjoint and linear. Finally, since $S$ is positive definite, both terms in the last line are positive, and hence the minimum is attained (but not necessarily *uniquely*?) when the first term is zero, i.e when $u=u_\star$.

### **QUESTION**

Both the proof, and the initial premise, are dependent on the fact that $U$ is a **real** inner product space. Not only does the proof rely on the symmetry of the inner product, which is clearly violated in a complex inner product space, but the initial premise that $Qu_\star\leq Qu$ for all $u\in U$ is nonsense when $Q$ is allowed to take complex values. *So*, what I'm interested in is, **is there any way to modify this idea to allow for complex inner product spaces?** Can we somehow fix $Q$ to only take real values, or somehow perhaps talk about minimizing the absolute value $|Qu|$?

I tried my best to adjust this theorem but I was unable to reach something concrete. I also searched the internet far and wide for results that generalized to complex inner product spaces but I was unable to dig up anything. Or perhaps, is there **NO** way to make this work in complex spaces? That would be even more interesting. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$Here is a straightfoward approach to reduce the complex case to the real one: Since for any $u \in U$, if $u$ satisfies $Su = f$, then $\<u, f\> = \<u, Su\> \in \R$, so it suffices to focus on the following subspace (over $\R$) of $U$:$$
U_f = \{u \in U \mid \<u, f\> \in \R\}.
$$
($U_f$ is indeed a linear space over $\R$ since $\<\,·\,,\,·\,\>$ is linear in the first argument).

Now suppose $Su = f$ admits a unique solution $u^* \in U_f$. For any $u \in U_f \setminus \{u^*\}$, note that $\<u, f\> \in \R$ implies that$$
\<f, u\> = \overline{\<u, f\>} = \<u, f\>,\quad \<u^*, Su\> = \<u, Su^*\> = \<u, f\>,
$$
thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom=} \<u - u^*, S(u - u^*)\>\\
&= \<u, Su\> - \<u, Su^*\> - \<u^*, Su\> + \<u^*, Su^*\>\\
&= \<u, Su\> - 2\<u, f\> + \<u^*, f\>\\
&= (\<u, Su\> - 2\<f, u\>) - (\<u^*, f\> - 2\<f, u^*\>)\\
&= (\<u, Su\> - 2\<f, u\>) - (\<u^*, Su^*\> - 2\<f, u^*\>)\\
&= 2(Qu - Qu^*),
\end{align*}
and$$
Qu - Qu^* = \frac{1}{2} \<u - u^*, S(u - u^*)\> > 0.
$$

Comment: Much simpler than I was expecting. If you could add something about why $u_\star$ is the unique minimizer of $Q$ I will be happy to accept and award the bounty.

Comment: @K.defaoite If $\widetilde u$ is another minimizer, then $Q\widetilde u<Qu^*$, contradictory to $Qu^*<Q\widetilde u$. Perhaps what you wanted to ask is something different?

Comment: At first I didn't see where we get uniqueness from, but I see it now - it comes from the last line from the fact $S$ is pos-def. Thanks.